# MySQL Count Numbers Are Off

Tags: mysql, count

I am not sure why my numbers are drastically off from each other.

A query with no max id:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as date, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test_ips
WHERE id > 0
AND viewip != ""
GROUP BY HOUR(t_stamp)
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC;
```

I get:

```
1     2012-07-18 19:00:00     1313
106     2012-07-18 20:00:00     1567
107     2012-07-19 09:00:00     847
225     2012-07-19 10:00:00     5095
421     2012-07-19 11:00:00     205
423     2012-07-19 12:00:00     900
461     2012-07-19 13:00:00     619
490     2012-07-20 15:00:00     729
575     2012-07-20 16:00:00     1682
1060     2012-07-20 17:00:00     2063
2260     2012-07-20 18:00:00     1417
5859     2012-07-20 21:00:00     1303
7060     2012-07-20 22:00:00     1340
8280     2012-07-20 23:00:00     1211
9149     2012-07-21 00:00:00     1675
10418     2012-07-21 01:00:00     721
11127     2012-07-21 02:00:00     825
```

But if I add a max id:

```
AND id <= 8279
```

I get:

```
1     2012-07-18 19:00:00     1313
106     2012-07-18 20:00:00     1201
107     2012-07-19 09:00:00     118
225     2012-07-19 10:00:00     196
421     2012-07-19 11:00:00     2
423     2012-07-19 12:00:00     38
461     2012-07-19 13:00:00     20
490     2012-07-20 15:00:00     85
575     2012-07-20 16:00:00     483
1060     2012-07-20 17:00:00     1200
2260     2012-07-20 18:00:00     1200
5859     2012-07-20 21:00:00     1201
7060     2012-07-20 22:00:00     1220
```

The numbers are WAY off from each other.  Something is goofy.

EDIT: Here is my table structure:

```
id  t_stamp             bID      viewip                 unique
1   2012-07-18 19:22:20     5    192.168.1.1        1
2   2012-07-18 19:22:21     1    192.168.1.1        1
3   2012-07-18 19:22:22     5    192.168.1.1        0
4   2012-07-18 19:22:22     3    192.168.1.1        1
```

Comment: Does the table field 'id' have auto_increment? Do you delete data from there?

Comment: Please clarify why you think the numbers are off, and provide sample data with desired output.

Comment: Yes, the id is auto-increment and the oldest record would be the lowest number, so everything is in order by ID and the t_stamp.  In fact, I do plan to delete entries later on, that's why id selection is so important.

Comment: RedFilter: The numbers are simply off because I should be able to see a count across the entire table or even a portion and get same answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not consistent.

In your select statement you are displaying the full date.

But you are grouping your data by the hour.  So your count statement is taking the count of all the data for each hour of the day.

As an example take your first result:

`1     2012-07-18 19:00:00     1313`

The count of 1313 contains the records for all of your dates (7/18, 7/19, 7/20, 7/21, 7/22, etc) that have an hour of 19:00.

But the way you have your query setup, it looks like it should be the count of all records for 2012-07-18 19:00:00.

So when you add AND id <= 8279" The dates of 7/21 and some of 7/20 or no longer being counted so your count values are now lower.

I'm guessing you are meaning to group by the date and hour and not just the hour.

Comment: Ahh, very correct, I wanted to group by date and hour.  How would I group by date and then the hours?

Comment: Just use what you used in the select. GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')

Comment: You're a winner! :)  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are not grouping by ID and I think you intend to.

Try:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as date, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test_ips
WHERE id > 0
    AND viewip != ""
GROUP BY id, DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
ORDER BY t_stamp;
```

Comment: The problem is that the ID is just a marker of which column it is.  I need to know the stats of these by hour.  Each record is a stat, so I really just need to know how many columns there are for each hour.

Comment: If you are not grouping by `ID`, you should not be selecting it, as the value returned is indeterminate.

Comment: That gives me the count for 1 for each line, so that's not working. :(

Comment: Then you don't need ID in your output, it is not meaningful :)

Comment: Correct, but that ID should not be causing this number difference.  In fact, if I remove id from the select, still gives me the same count output, so something is wrong.

Comment: No, but adding `AND id <= 8279` to the` WHERE` clause causes fewer rows to be returned, and thus lower counts.

Comment: Yes, correct, though all of my counts are in chronological order.  Record #1 is older than Record #2.  Should never be a record that is older.  I even sorted it that way for t_stamp.